# How to print specific key with key and value

Tags: python

```
A = {
  "Ajit": {
    "Place": "Bharasar",
    "Age": "20"
  },
  "Deepika": {
    "Place": "Mankuva",
    "Age": "19"
  }
}
```

I want to print specific key `Ajit` with `Ajit`'s key it self like:

```
{
  'Ajit': {
    'Place': 'Bharasar',
    'Age':'20'
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want the output as a string or as another dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You just create a new Dict like the following code:

```
A = {
  "Ajit": {
    "Place": "Bharasar",
    "Age": "20"
  },
  "Deepika": {
    "Place": "Mankuva",
    "Age": "19"
  }
}
    
B = {
   "Ajit": A["Ajit"]
}
    
print(B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
A = {"Ajit":{"Place":"Bharasar","Age":"20"}, "Deepika":{"Place":"Mankuva","Age":"19"}} 
key = "Ajit"
print(f"{{'{key}': {A[key]}}}")
```

And please remember to put four spaces before your code samples to get proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Ajit` value, you can get it with `A["Ajit"]`
However, if you want to have the key and its associated value, you can print

```
A = {
  "Ajit": {
    "Place": "Bharasar",
    "Age": "20"
  },
  "Deepika": {
    "Place": "Mankuva",
    "Age": "19"
  }
}

key = "Ajit"
print("{" + key + ":" + A[key] + "}")
```